# How are functions, function arguments, and local stack physically organized in memory?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction

I'd like to understand what it *really* means when one reads from a debugger that such-and-such a function lives at address `0xsuchandsuch`, that variable `foo` at address `0xfoosaddress` points to a region of memory at address `0xpointedmemory`, and so on.

**Where can I find resources on how memory gets organized for programs compiled from C? Is it compiler-specific? Platform-specific?**

Comment: It's compiler and platform specific :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the platform (combination of CPU and operating system) determines how memory is managed. The compiler has to obey the rules set by the platform.  These are usually specified in something called ABI (application binary interface).  For Solaris (mostly valid also for other UNIX-like systems), you can learn a lot from the book "Expert C Programming" by Peter van der Linden.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely Implementation defined(both compiler & platform specific).
The Standard does not talk of any memory regions it just states the desired behavior.

Usually(again implementation specific in reality), a compiled c program would be organized in to different memory regions.

***Write Great Code vol 1*** by ***Ryndall hyde*** classifys these sections for one of the implementations as:

- **Code Section**  - holds programs machine instructions
- **Constant Section** - holds compiler generated read only data
- **Read only data Section** - holds user-defined data that only be read, never written
- **Static Section** - holds user defined ,initialized static variables
- **BSS Section** - holds user-defined un - initialized variables
- **Stack Section** - holds local variables & other temporary data
- **Heap Section** - holds dynamic variables
- **Reserved Section** for O.S

Answer (score 0):

For intel machines, you can start near the beginning: [8086](http://www.ee.unb.ca/tervo/ee6373/subs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can divide computers into two categories:

1) Small systems, like those of embedded systems today (even though many desktop computers used to look like this, back in the days). There is only one big memory range, and when the linker says it is located at a specific address, it really is stored there.

2) Big systems, with memory management systems. In these systems, each process is presented with a view that looks like a full memory range, but the address it uses might not correspond to the physical addresses of the real memory. In addition, parts of memory could be swapped to disk and later be re-read at another physical address. This is one reason why one often talk about *location* rather than *address* of objects.

I would recommend that you start with a simple compiler for a simple compiler and see what it outputs. For example, you could use the embedded processor MSP430 and, say, the free Kickstart version of the IAR compiler. The manual describes how memory is organized and how the startup process is performed etc.